# How does the Set interface guarantees non duplicates

Tags: java, set

Today the interviewer asked me: How does Set guarantees non duplicates?

Comment: The *interface* only says what *implementations* have to achieve - not how they achieve it. You would need to ask about one specific implementation.

Comment: `More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element.` Maybe he is asking what constraint does `Set` enforce? E.g., `equals` instead of identity or `hashCode`.

Comment: @Victor Are you on ask-interview-questions spree ?

Comment: May the interviewer just want to hear - *The interface only specifies that the implementations have to guarantee non duplicates.* Just a guess :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the source code of `add` method. For example in source code of `TreeSet` the add method is implemented as follows:

```
public boolean add(E e) 
{
    return m.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Where, `PRESENT` is an object of `Object` class. And `m` is the object of `NavigableMap`. This `NavigableMap` `m` is used to store the element `e` as `key`  and `PRESENT` as its `value` to the given key `e`. Consequently every key in `m` has same object `PRESENT`. The `put` method of `Map` as defined within oracle doc is :

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced. 
>   ...
>   ...
>   Returns: the **previous value associated with key**, or *null if there was no mapping for key*. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)

So, When you put the duplicate element within set this element is put in the `NavigableMap` as key with value `PRESENT`. If this key was not present in `NavigableMap` then `put` method returns `null` and hence
`m.put(e,PRESENT)==null` returns true and we come to know that the element is added. And if the key is already present in `NavigableMap` then `put` method overrided the `value` for the `key` `e` within `NavigableMap` with PRESENT  and returns the old value (which is PRESENT) and hence
`m.put(e,PRESENT)==null` returns `false` and we come to know that the element is not added.

Comment: This only answers the question for `TreeSet`. The question is about `Set.` As asked, the original question doesn't actually make sense, but this isn't an answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Set is an abstract data type that can be implemented in many ways. On its own it's a specification of a contract; as such it does not guarantee anything. It's up to the *implementation of the interface* to guarantee that the contract is fulfilled.

Therefore it's more interesting to look at how and why the implementations work. Some common implementations are:

- Hash table, as implemented in Java by `HashSet`
- Balanced tree, as implemented in Java by `TreeSet`
- Bit set (for special types), as implemented in Java by `EnumSet` and `BitSet`
- Skip lists, as implemented by `ConcurrentSkipListSet`
- Naive arrays: scan the array for the element before adding it; not frequently used. Implemented in Java as `CopyOnWriteArraySet`

In a job interview you would have replied with the above and offered to explain the details of any one implementation. The interviewer should already know some of these and it wouldn't have been to your benefit to start rambling about them unless asked.

Comment: ...but how does that answer the question?

Comment: Like this: *Q: How does set guarantee non-duplicates? A: There are many ways in which it can do it. For example A, B, C, or D.*

Comment: yes, but those guarantees are upheld by the impl, not the interface. i could write a set implementation that uses an ArrayList store and completely break this guarantee.

Comment: Ah, I understand your point now. An interface does not guarantee anything; it's up to the implementation to guarantee that the interface is fulfilled. Therefore it's more interesting to look at how and why the implementations work.

Comment: It's interesting to look at how and why implementations work, but interfaces fulfil an important function as well - in particular, they impose requirements on all implementations that conform to them. Someone can fail to conform to the interface by writing a bad implementation, but that's their fault - as the user of a `Set`, it should be reasonable to assume that anyone who implements `Set` (particularly in the context of a standard library implementation) does it right. If they don't, it's their bug not yours.

Comment: The key point here is not about blame, but about the fact that as a client you can write your code against a particular interface without having to worry about the implementation details - you're adding a layer of abstraction between the implementation of the data structure and client code, helping to decouple the two.

Answer (score 1):

From a specification point of view, it achieves it by e.g. specifying what the `add` method must do if you try and add a duplicate. The documentation for the `add` method says this, for example:

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present
>   (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to
>   this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ?
>   e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element,
>   the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination
>   with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never
>   contain duplicate elements.

From the same page (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> The additional stipulation on constructors is, not surprisingly, that all constructors must create a set that contains no duplicate elements (as defined above).

(For completeness, there are also stipulations with regard to `equals` and `hashCode` that ensure that `Set` properly models the set abstraction.)